# why I am getting error in the code in nextjs script tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a file 'blog.js' in pages folder and a file 'al.js' in public folder
This is the code in my blog.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Home(){
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>blog</title>
      </Head>
        <Script 
          src='/al.js'
          strategy='lazyOnload'
        />
      <main>
      ........
    </main>
    </>
    )
}
```

Then why I am not getting the script included

Comment: Can you share the error message you get?

Comment: Actually I don't get any error except 404 page not found, when I add script tag

Comment: Can you share the code for the `al.js` script?

Comment: Its nothing but a simple alert

Answer (score 0):

Could you share what do you want to achieve and error?

Script component is used to render 3rd party scripts to set the loading priority of third-party scripts in order to improve web performance.
More detailed information can be found in [official doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) of next.js

If its just loading the JavaScript file then u can directly do in Head tag.

```
 <Head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="[PATH]"></script>
</Head>
```

Comment: Actually I am not getting an error, when I add the script tag, the browser shows 404 page not found